# Cleaning script with find and anacron

Tags: find, cron

I want to automatically delete old files in ~/Downloads.
with exception of ones that have '!' in their name.
My current version is as follows:

```
find /home/user/Downloads/ -mtime +90 ! -path '*!*' -delete
```

When I test it as follows*:

```
find /home/user/Downloads/ -depth -mtime +90 ! -path '*!*' -print
```

The result is:

```
/home/user/Downloads/old.file
/home/user/Downloads
```

I don't want it to delete my `/home/user/Downloads` directory that will still contain `!protected.old.file`

I want this to be run from anacron so I'm not sure if using globing there is a good idea.

*Notice that `-depth` is implied by `-delete`.

Comment: Why haven't you restricted to files: `-type f`?

Comment: @muru Because I also want old subdirectories to be deleted.

Comment: OK. Then why not `-mindepth 1`?

Comment: @muru Well that is the solution. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is protect the path given to `find` from being deleted, use `-mindepth 1`. I'd split the action, however: run once, deleting only files, and run again, this time deleting directories using `rmdir`, which will only remove empty directories. Note that deleting a file should change the access and modify times of the containing directory, so the test becomes invalid for an old directory as soon as any file in it is deleted. Hence, deleting empty directories in a second run is more likely to succeed.